# UnicodeDecodeError while identifying file type-gz or zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code to identify if given file is gz or zip file. However, it returns error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

Can you please help me with what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
    header_dict = {
        "\x1f\x8b\x08": "gz",
        "\x50\x4b\x03\x04": "zip"
    }
    len_max = max(len(x) for x in header_dict)
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_start = f.read(len_max)
    for header, file_type in header_dict.items():
        if file_start.startswith(header):
            return file_type
    return "no match"
```

Comment: Why do you make `header_dict` a dictionary when you're iterating through the whole thing anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary mode so it doesn't try to decode the bytes.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```

Then make your test strings binary too:

```
header_dict = {
    b"\x1f\x8b\x08": "gz",
    b"\x50\x4b\x03\x04": "zip"
}
```